# Android: Google plus Button loading never stop

Tags: android, google-plus

I been following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend) to implement Google +1 button.

I verified that I am getting `ConnectionCallbacks.onConnected` from my `PlusClient` listener.

It shows me how many people +1 this, but when I am trying to click the button it start loading and never stop.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: You should add your code to your question so people can help diagnose.

Comment: Same problem here... I didn't have this problem few hours ago and it suddenly appeared on my S4 4.2.2. No problem on my tablet 3.x. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: I put a listener like this on my +1 button:

```
mPlusOneButton.setOnPlusOneClickListener
```

as mentioned here: [PlusOneButton on Android how to know if user has clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695035/plusonebutton-on-android-how-to-know-if-user-has-clicked/17840419#17840419)

and it created the bug...

Don't use this listener !!!

Answer (score -1):

You have to be logged in first to be able to use the +1 feature safely.