# PlusOneButton on Android how to know if user has clicked?

Tags: android, listener, google-plus-one

In my Android app I am giving the possibility to tap on a Google +1 button.

This works fine with the following code from the developpers source material (https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend):

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
    .clearScopes()
    .build();  

mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
```

Now I would like to detect when the user taps on this button, so I tried this:

```
mPlusOneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {                   
        Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks for your +1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

But it doesn't do anything, it doesn't display the toast message.

As an alternative, I was thinking of having the player tap twice on the button : first being a regular Button object that would make the plus one button visible, second being the plusone button. but it is an awckward user experience

How can I detect user's tap on this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plus one button provides a listener function to detect button click. Here is the code.

```
    mPlusOneButton.setOnPlusOneClickListener(new PlusOneButton.OnPlusOneClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlusOneClick(Intent intent) {
            Log.w(tag,"plus one click");

        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried this with Google Plus SDK v.13. It induced the following bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833038/android-google-plus-sdk-progress-indicator-progressbar-never-stops-after-clic Don't use this listener !!! (test on SDK 13)

Comment: This is not a bug, you should start the `intent` own your own http://stackoverflow.com/a/16561771/1192761

Answer (score 3):

Don't use setOnPlusOneClickListener (or any listener) with SDK 13 (and perhaps future versions), it induces a bug (infinite rotation of the progress indicator in the +1 button when you click on it).

Comment: You can use it, but you have to start the `intent` on your own see:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16561771/1192761

Answer (score 2):

Use ActivityForResult to trigger the user choice.

```
mPlusOneButton.setOnPlusOneClickListener(new PlusOneButton.OnPlusOneClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlusOneClick(Intent intent) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            });
```

Check the result code

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == -1) {
      // OK or SHARE

    } else {
      //UNDO

    }

}
```

Comment: +vote for your answer !...  I need to know only if OK is pressed. Any way ?

Comment: @iappmaker ,You can use SharePreference to save the state of user choice in `onActivityResult`

Comment: The resultCode of -1 will not be able to determine if the user pressed OK or SHARE. Hence how do I know user has pressed only OK and not SHARE

Comment: It's not possible, in fact, if the button is already in +1 and you click it again it will return 0, and if it's +1 and click undo you will get -1 instead of 0.