# Android Google Plus SDK: progress indicator (ProgressBar) never stops after click on +1 button

Tags: android, api, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-one

I implemented the +1 button in my Android app. Almost everything works fine:

- I can log in /log out
- when I am logged in, the +1 button tells what is the number of +1 and becomes red/white in compliance with the fact that I did or not a +1 on my webpage

BUT....when I click on the +1 button, an activity indicator (progress indicator (ProgressBar)) appears on my +1 button (which becomes white) and it never stops rotating ! The window to cancel/share/make a +1 never appears...

Note that I have another activity with a +1 button in my app and that the +1 button in this other activity works perfectly well...

I don't understand what is the problem !

A ny idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: I did have a listener like this on my PlusOneButton...:

[PlusOneButton on Android how to know if user has clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695035/plusonebutton-on-android-how-to-know-if-user-has-clicked/17840419#17840419)

Very bad idea... It induces this bug !!

Don't use this listener ! If anybody has a solution to put a listener without inducing a bug, let me know ! I would like to track the number of clicks on this button...

Also, be sure that you are signed in (you have to include the code to sign in).

Comment: I am having same problem.i can login /logout,by default i can't enable G+1 button.pls let me know when u fixed.if u know first,i will let u know

Answer (score 0):

try this.it has bug when user undo the +1
.

```
        mPlusButton.setOnPlusOneClickListener(new PlusOneButton.OnPlusOneClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPlusOneClick(Intent intent) {
         try {
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(HomeActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       }
   });
```